# Who proved the reflection principle in random walks and Brownian motion?

Tags: pr.probability, random-walks, brownian-motion

I've heard Henry McKean say that the reflection principle is due to Désiré André. But the wikipedia page seems to say that André did not use a reflection principle. Does anyone know where the "modern" version of the reflection principle was first proved, at least for random walk and Brownian motion?

Comment: See http://webspace.ship.edu/msrenault/ballotproblem/monthly358-363-renault.pdf and http://webspace.ship.edu/msrenault/ballotproblem/.